# I cant find out what i should have in my return statement

Tags: java

Ok so I am new to programming(Don't laugh at me if I ask a question very easy).
A sample of my code is as follows:

```
public int calcGCF(int mya, int mye, int myf, int myj)
{
    x = myj * myf;
    y = mye* mya;

        while(x != 0 && y != 0)
        {
            if(x % y == 0)
            {
                 remainder = y; 
            }

        int gcf;
        gcf = y;
        y = x % y;
        x = gcf;
       }
}
```

Ok. So what this code is for is to potentially solve the derivative of any problem that the user inputs. Part of solving the derivative is getting a gcf of 2 numbers and factoring it out. When I try to compile this code, it says that I am missing a return statement. I understand what that is, but when I try to say "return remainder;" it says it may not have been initialized. Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong in this code, and help me with what I should put in my return statement? Thank You! By the way this is with java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where are the variables `x`, `y`, and `remainder` declared? I don't see an `int remainder;` statement anywhere in the code you posted. There's also no `return` statement in the method, so it will not compile.

Local variables (variables that you declare inside a method) must be initialized with a value before you use them anywhere where you read the value. If you do this, for example:

```
public int method(int a) {
    int value;

    if (a > 10) {
        value = 99;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Then you will get the same error as you are getting, because in case `a` is not greater than 10, the variable `value` isn't assigned any value when you reach the `return` statement - so Java doesn't know what value to return then.

You must make sure that `value` is assigned a value in any possible case.

Answer (score 0):

As you wish you can return the remainder. Just initialize your remainder to a value. eg: remainder=0;

Answer (score 0):

> I understand what that is, but when I try to say "return remainder;" it says it may not have been initialized.

So you simply need to declare, at the top of your code, something like:

```
remainder = 0;
```

I would also think about naming your variables a little more appropriately than just `myj`.